swift 6 default parameter: Actor-isolated property 'bar' can not be referenced from a nonisolated context
I have to code below.
actor BarActor {
    
    var bar: Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    static let barActor: BarActor = BarActor()
    
    func add(theBar: Int = BarActor.barActor.bar) -> Int { //Error is here.
        return theBar + 100
    }
}

The error is:
Actor-isolated property 'bar' can not be referenced from a nonisolated context


I am a bit confused the property bar is referenced in function add which is in its own actor already in my understanding.
How to make it add has the default value BarActor.barActor.bar? thanks!

Well add is isolated to self, but barActor.bar is isolated to barActor. Actor isolation is not just about the actor types, but individual instances of actors.

Also note that default parameters are evaluated in the context of the caller. That won't make a difference here but it's important to understand the difference.

Perhaps you mean you want to use self.bar as the default value? In that case write theBar: Int? = nil as the parameter and do theBar ?? bar in the body of add.

@Sweeper you are right. I want to use BarActor.barActor.bar as default parameter. It's one option use optional parameter.

If you want to use BarActor.barActor.bar, then add would have to be async. Perhaps you want BarActor to be a @globalActor instead, since there seems to be a shared instance?

This feels like an XY Problem. You should explain why you want to do this, and what the context is.
